# ClassNotFound Exception Occured while consuming JMS ObjectMessage

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, classnotfoundexception

I am consuming a JMS `ObjectMessage` through a listener written in Spring Boot. I am sending the `ObjectMessage` through my Camel application to a JMS queue and I am listening to the queue from my listener class in my Spring Boot application.

Code:

```java
final BindyCsvDataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(EquityFeeds.class);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
CamelContext _ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
_ctx.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
_ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data.csv")               
            .unmarshal(bindy)
            .split(body())
            .streaming().to("jms:queue:javaobjects.upstream.queue");
    }
});
```

Here is my POJO class `EquityFeeds`:

```java
@CsvRecord(separator = ",",skipFirstLine = true)
public class EquityFeeds implements Serializable {
        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
    @DataField(pos = 1) 
    private String externalTransactionId;
        
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String clientId;
    
    // other fields and getters setters
    ...
```

In the JMS queue I am receiving the message as:

```
camelproject.EquityFeeds@1665425
```

My JMS listener in Spring Boot:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "javaobjects.upstream.queue")
public void capitalIQProcessor(final Message objectMessage) throws JMSException {
    Object messageData = null;
    
    if(objectMessage instanceof ObjectMessage) {
        ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) objectMessage;
        System.out.println("Starting Object Message.");
    
        Object object = objMessage.getObject();
    
        EquityFeeds equityFeeds = (EquityFeeds) object;
    
        System.out.println("Object: "+equityFeeds.toString());
    }    
}
```

I am getting an Exception @ line `Object object = objMessage.getObject();`:

```
capitalIQProcessor(javax.jms.Message) throws javax.jms.JMSException' threw exception; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: camelproject.EquityFeeds. Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: camelproject.EquityFeeds. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: camelproject.EquityFeeds
```

Through Stack Overflow and other posts on the net I made the following changes:

1. I made the changes to `wrapper.conf` (apache-activemq-5.15.11-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.11\bin\win64)

   1. Added then entry:
      `wrapper.java.classpath.3=C:\Users\sidbharg\eclipse-workspace\Sid\target\camelproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
      This is the location of the .jar file where I have my POJO (EquityFeeds).
   2. Also added the entry:
      `wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"`
2. In My Consumer code I also added `activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);`:

```java
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}
```

Now what is the issue? Why its giving me the exception. Where I am going wrong? Is there anything which I have forgotten and is needed to be added?

Comment: Why are you using a JMS `ObjectMessage`? It's discouraged for multiple reasons.

Comment: @Justin: I understand that its discouraged for mulitple reasons but still I have a requirement to do it and so can't help it.

Comment: You have a specific requirement to use `ObjectMessage` even though technically the data could be transferred in other kinds of messages which are safer and don't suffer from the same limitations? Typically requirements aren't expressed at the implementation level like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need `camelproject.EquityFeeds` on the classpath of the application consuming the JMS `ObjectMessage`. Apparently the JVM can't find it and therefore throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Also, you don't need those changes to the broker's `wrapper.conf`. The *listener* is trying to deserialize the message, not the broker.

Comment: I have camel.EquityFeeds in the classpath of my listener application which is written in SpringBoot which is consuming the JMS ObjectMessage. I wonder why JVM can't find it. I do understand the listener is trying to deserialize the message not the broker. I did those changes to see the object in the broker i.e. ActiveMQ. How do I make SpringBoot understand that camelproject.EquityFeeds is in it's classpath. How do I resolve this issue.

Comment: I just solved this issue. I gave the same package name structure for my POJO class EquityFeeds as in my Spring Boot application. That solved the issue.